# .footer() on column returns null, although footer is there

Tags: javascript, datatables

I'm using DataTables 1.10.15 and have the most basic table imaginable like

```
<table>
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th>Foo</th>
   <th>Bar</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tfoot>
  <tr>
   <td>Foo</td>
   <td>Bar</td>
  </tr>
 </tfoot>
 <tbody>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

On `document.ready` I access the footer nodes to add per-column-search callbacks; however `.footer()` on all column-objects only returns `null` and I have no idea why this is.

```
... table is the DT-object
table.columns().every(function() { console.log(this.footer()) })
```

... just prints a lot of `null`. `.header()` works without problems and `table.table(0).footer()` is in fact the footer node. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that for some reason pulling the i18n file via ajax in the constructor causes `.footer()` to fail. Passing the literal values fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You did not provide the full code but you need to have an instance of `table`

**Working example :** https://jsfiddle.net/jondion/ab2avuzk/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('table').DataTable();
    table.columns().every(function() { 
    console.log(this.footer()) // data...
  })
});
```

jQuery 2.2.4

DataTables 1.10.15

Comment: I didn't point out that `table` is in fact the initialized DT-object. `.header()` works, that's what's confusing to me.

Comment: You need to use a callback: https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/footer_callback.html